# how to implement wait,notify with threadexecutor in java

Tags: java, multithreading

how to implement wait,notify with threadexecutor in java,Suppose I have two objeccts of threadExecutor and I want to perform wait,notify on that objecct can we implement that.

Comment: What do you mean by "threadExecutor"? Are you referring to "ThreadPoolExecutor"? ExecutorService? Can you show pertinent code and give more background information?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels offcourse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Example of using wait notify with ThreadExecutor in Java :

```
public class ExecutorServiceTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        ThreadB threadB = new ThreadB();
        ThreadA threadA = new ThreadA(threadB);

        executor.execute(threadA);
        executor.execute(threadB);

        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated());
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");

    }

    static class ThreadA extends Thread {

        private final ThreadB waitThread;

        public ThreadA(ThreadB waitThread) {
            this.waitThread = waitThread;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (waitThread) {
                try {
                    waitThread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("B Count Total : " + waitThread.getCount());

                for (int i = waitThread.getCount(); i < 200; i++) {
                    System.out.println("A Counting " + i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class ThreadB extends Thread {

        private int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (count < 100) {
                    System.out.println("B Counting " + count);
                    count++;
                }
                notify();
            }
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

    }

}
```

synchronized

> keyword is used for exclusive accessing.
>
> To make a method synchronized, simply add the synchronized keyword to its declaration. Then no two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object can interleave with each other.
>
> synchronized statements must specify the object that provides the intrinsic lock:

wait()

> tells the calling thread to give up the monitor and go to sleep until some other thread enters the same monitor and calls notify( ).

notify()

> wakes up the first thread that called wait() on the same object.

Comment: Ashraful I know this way, can we do using Executor

Comment: @pankajlal Updated the answer, Wait and Notify using ThreadExecutor